# Create a collection in Adobe Lightroom Classic given the file names (including path)

Tags: lightroom

How can I create a collection (or simply filter) in Adobe Lightroom Classic given a list of file names (including directory/path). I tried to use the text filter but this only works for file names without path - which unfortunately isn't good enough, since I have files with the same name in different directories.

Comment: do you have enough space to create copies of your picks in a new common folder? Then it's easy to feed to LRC. You can use symlinks or shortcuts instead of copying to save space if you're good on the command line. There's many ways to turna  text list of paths into a shellscript or batch file that will do this for you, ask around superuser.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is in Collections add Smart collection with match field Folder contains and/or Filename contains. See the image below for visualization.
[image]

Comment: My list of files has around 1000 entries, therefore this solution is not working for me.

Comment: @Nausika, this create specific collection. And will work with much more photos. Just need to refine your criterias.

Comment: Yes. What I meant is, that I already have a list (in a text file) and I want to filter (or create a collection) in Lightroom. If I understood your suggestion correctly, I would need to create the rules manually for each file, i.e. I can't just copy-paste my already existing list. When filtering in Lightroom I can copy-past all the filenames from the list (but I can't use filenames with paths).

Comment: @Nausika, no. You need to import all photos in Lightroom and create collection to filter and see only part of imported photos based on your path criterias. Via collections you filter what you want to see.